# Не работают @media правила ни Chrome, ни в Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Не работают медиа правила. Не отображаются даже в DevTools ни в одном из браузеров. Медиа я писал в самом конце всех стилей. В шапке подключил:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Может, проблема в том, что нет основных правил (не медиа) для конкретно этого блока (только для дочерних в нём)? Или это особенности Wordpress какие-то?

```
@media screen(max-width: 1280px) {
    .header_info .row .row1 {
        display: none;
    }

    .header_info .row .row1 .phone {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Вот сам сайт:[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://avto.fof.com.ua/)

Comment: Используйте следующую форму: `@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас **and** перед (max-width: 1280px) пропущено. Должно быть:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

}
```

Comment: да, ошибка в этом была. Только я не дописывал "and" а просто убрал "screen":

@media (max-width: 1280px) {

}

Comment: @nirolo1, или так :)

Answer (score -1):

В WordPress нет ни одной особенности, связанной с css, да и не может быть, потому что стили распознаются браузером.

> Может, проблема в том, что нет основных правил (не медиа)

Нет, и не в этом. Стили могут быть указаны только в media, и нигде больше.

Что тогда? Самая распространённая ошибка - незакрытая скобка внутри файла css. После этого все, что ниже, браузер просто игнорирует.

Comment: Нет, не в этом, ошибка была в том что было слово "screen" но не было "and" т.е нужно либо дописать либо вообще не писать "screen".

Comment: Я увидел это в ответе humster. Ну и хорошо. Зато я вам на два других момента ответил в вашем вопросе - вы не заметили?

Comment: Это да. С этим согласен))